# writing an iOS app to pay utility bill

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Ok, I have a client who is a utility provider (like power, water, etc).  They want their customers to be able to pay their bill from an iOS app.  Since this isn't a product will it be okay to use an alternative payment gateway using WebView?

Comment: what is the point of using a web view? I'm sure your client can create the mobile version of their web site that people can use to pay their utility. it is done by all the other guys.

Answer (score 2):

This specific usage sounds fine. Apple doesn't allow you to sell app content through anything but the store, but taking payment for an entirely external service should be fine, there are dozens of similar apps for general payment processing (LevelUp, 4square, etc.), and this is the same sort of thing, just for a more specific debt.

That said, if all your app is is a WebView wrapper for your site, Apple will reject it because of that. An app that wraps a webview must additionally use a nontrivial amount of native functionality.

Comment: Yes, they plan on doing more than a WebView. That's just one part of the whole App experience.  We are also considering jQuery Mobile, but think the user experience and UI would be more responsive using a hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if your application is just a `UIWebView` embedded in a `UIView`, it will almost certainly be rejected. What is the benefit of an application embedding a mobile version of the website, compared to just loading the mobile site in the default Safari web browser?

If you are going to do this, Apple requires that the application be more than just a web browser loading a default URL. This can be one component of the app, but it cannot be the only component.